# same shell script not working on different environmnet

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, batch-file

I have just basic knowledge on Unix and know how to run shell script.
Process: we have created a batch (ex:test.bat)which will call shell script(shelltest.sh) by passing arguments.

when user enter a command on UI application front,the test.bat file will invoke with command-line( ex: test.bat "-h checkwriter -A 20141203")

bat file is calling sh file and passing arguments ,but the problems is i have a function/method in the sh file to verify certain checks ,this check is within the while block.
here the function is calling but exiting without entering into the while condition.

The same shell script working fine on testing environments but where as which is failing on PROD environment.

test.bat

```
sh shelltest.sh
```

shelltest.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
#set -x

PROGRAMNAME=`basename $0` 
echo "Prog name is $PROGRAM"                                             
QUIT=0

Check_test()
{

echo "Check1:$@"
echo "Check2:$#"
echo "Check3:$*"

echo "Param1 : is $1"
echo "Param2 : is $2"
echo "Param3 : is $3"


while [ $# -ne 0 ]
      do
         case `echo $1 | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"` in

                 -K)          
                     echo "Inside MYVAR before:${1}"
                     shift
                     MYVAR=${1}
                     echo "Inside MYVAR after:${1}"
                     ;;
                  *) 
                     echo "Inside what is"
                     ;;

                    esac

                  if [ $# -ne 0 ]
                  then
                    shift
                  fi
       done     

     if [ "${MYVAR}" == "" ]
       then 
         echo "Failed to enter into while condition "
         QUIT=1;
     fi
}

Check_test $*
```

Output of the above code for respective environment is,

```
**'---The out put in Testing environment  (-K checkwriter -A 20141203) 
Prog name is shelltest.sh 
Check1 : -K checkwriter -A 20141203 
Check2 : 4 
Check3 : -K checkwriter -A 20141203 
'after entered in while loop 
Inside MYVAR before:-K 
Inside MYVAR after: checkwriter**

**'----The output in PROD environment
Prog name is (no file is coming...it is empty)
Check1 : -K checkwriter -A 20141203
Check2 : 4
Check3 : -K checkwriter -A 20141203
'Not entering into while loop
Failed to enter into while condition**
```

the above shell script giving out put what am expecting,but in PROD environment it is failing to enter into the while loop. and one more 'basename' also coming as empty in prod.

Please,any one can suggest me how i can fix this issue.

Note: we are running on windows machine but to support unix commands we got installed some 3rd party apis.

Comment: Which OS / distribution, version and bash version do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit,bash version i don't know but tried with both ksh and bash. same environment was available for testing and working there. one more information i could see arguments which i passed from batch file ,i used ${1},${2},${3}...which are coming correctly but when it enters within the method failing at while condition.

Comment: Don't use bash in Windows. Port it to batch or Powershell.

Comment: i used #!/bin/ksh and working in my testing environment and am not able to reproduce the same issue what am facing on PROD environment.don't mind how i can port it to Powershell. am calling this shell script file from batch file.

Comment: `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` with spaces as shown

Comment: Can you give a full copy-paste showing the script giving expected output, and then a full copy-paste showing it fail (presumably with errors) in prod?

Comment: I have updated my original code and out put of respective environment,please check

Comment: Please,anyone can assist to fix the issue...its a serious issue and impacted our business.